# tastypie save_m2m, TagRelatedManager evaluates to False

Tags: python, tastypie, django-tagging, django-related-manager

Actually, I'm trying to save a tastypie model resource which contains a `TagField` from [django-tagulous](http://radiac.net/projects/django-tagulous/)

Here are my model, and resources:

```
# models.py
class SimpleModel(models.Model):
    topics = tagulous.models.TagField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)


# resources.py
class TopicResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = SimpleModel.topics.tag_model.objects.all()
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()


class SimpleModelResource(ModelResource):
    tags = fields.ToManyField(TopicResource, attribute='topics', full=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = SimpleModel.objects.all()
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
```

the curl part:

```
curl --request POST --dump-header - --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"tags": ["/api/v1/topic/1/"], "title": "A bad dream"}' localhost:8000/api/v1/simplemodel/
```

The shell doesn't return any error, however, the tags are not associated with the new object.

By overriding the `ModelResource save_m2m method`, before the `super` call the tag object is present (print bundle.data['tags']), then in the `super(SimpleModelResource, self).save_m2m(bundle)` tastypie looks for the related manager associated with the tags field, the related_mngr is returned but when it is evaluated using: `if not related_mngr` it evaluates to `True` skiping the m2m association.

Comment: What if you change it to `"topics": ["/api/v1/topic/1/"]` instead?

Comment: Same error. I think it arises from the way the third part app is creating the manager for the `TagField`. Here's the reference: https://github.com/radiac/django-tagulous/blob/master/tagulous/models/descriptors.py#L204, BTW the related manager is returning a `TagRelatedManager`, which is created there: https://github.com/radiac/django-tagulous/blob/master/tagulous/models/descriptors.py#L251

Comment: Follow the issue at: https://github.com/radiac/django-tagulous/issues/9